# Websockets, run very long task and change configuration when task is running

Tags: python, events, tornado

I have a simple websocket server in python using tornado. It works perfectly but i need one feature i'm not sure how to implement. So there is a websocket server which listen on my port. Now when this server receive a message, i need accord with this message switch operation and run very long taking time task or cancel runned task (task runned by this server). It should looks like this:

```
class WSHandler(tornado.websocket.WebSocketHandler):
def open(self):
    print 'new connection'
    self.write_message("Hello World")

def on_message(self, message):
    #unpack message
    command = message[:2]
    taskid = message[2:4]
    print 'some message'
    if command == '00':
       # starting task with id = 1 which will take over 1 hour or more
       task.start() #it will take more than 1 hour!
    elif command == '01':
       # cancel task with id = 1
       task.stop()
    elif command == 'SomeOtherOptionsINeedToHandle':
       # Do the others
       task.internal_loop.change_configuration

def on_close(self):
  print 'connection closed'
```

i'm a little confused, i hope you can give me some tips. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

A couple ways to accomplish this, personally I'd look into celery and rabbit mq. A queueing server is nice in this case because you drop off the message and return on the socket so you don't block the socket connection. You'll pass in a call back function that will return once it's done that you can use to pipe the results to the correct function.

The tornado way is to use a gen.coroutine which works really great, I just happen to like the ability to drop a message in a queue any have kind of client pick it up not just the tornado server. Here the link to the docs: [tornado gen docs](http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/gen.html)